# Image Does Not Fill Container

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This is my first time posting here and I'm entirely self-taught, so bear with me please if I misspeak or say some dumb things.

I have a Wordpress blog. For quite some time, I have had my blog post format set up so that a "header image" displays across the width of the content space. Across the bottom of that image, I list the title of the post and the date.

To do this, I created what I believe is called a class -- I named it "container" and the only defining trait of this class is that it has "position: relative;" inside it's brackets. (It also has a "shadow" border. I tried taking this out and it had no effect.) This was done in the "additional CSS" section of the wordpress site.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px -1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);

}
```

I also made a class called "text-block" that is defined as follows:

```
.text-block {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(128,128,128,0.6);
  color: white;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Each post begins with opening a container. Then, immediately inside of the container is the image, with the width set to 100%. Then, still in the container, I put the text-block in, which is oriented across the bottom. The background color is opaque so that you still see the image behind the text, slightly greyed out.

Here is the code that begins the post of which I've attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx4Xy.jpg):

```
<div class="container"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-8056 size-full" style="width: 100%;" src="https://*mysite*/wp-content/uploads/thx-1138-film-confession.png" alt="Robert Duvall as THX 1138" width="831" height="364">
<div class="text-block">
<h2 style="color: white;"><em>THX 1138</em></h2>
<h6 style="color: white;">Review by *me* | November 6, 2020</h6>
</div>
</div>
```

The crucial part that I need to ask some advice on is the bottom edge of the container. Until recently, the bottom edges of the image, the text-block, and the container all coincided. Now, instead, a small amount of excess "padding" was added to the bottom of the container. So now, the text-block overlaps the image and some un-filled space beneath it, as you can see in the image. I can't seem to attach a second image of what it *should* look like, but I think it is clear what I'm trying to achieve.

I don't know where this excess "padding" came from. I didn't change anything -- no CSS was changed. I was just writing individual posts, copy-pasting the format from an old post to a new one to get the correct formatting. I was previewing a single new post when I realized the change, and I thought that I had messed something up on that individual post. But then I started clicking through my site and realized every single post now showed the error.

In the past, some other weird formatting things have happened that stemmed from a plug-in. I've deactivated all plug-ins and the issue remained. I've taken the text-block out entirely and the excess "padding" remains.

Like I said, I'm self-taught. I've really only learned things as I needed to know them. So it's possible I'm missing something simple or committing some grave error without knowing it. But it seems to me that my container lacks the definition that would cause it to be larger than an exact fit to what I put inside of it. Further, the fact that I did not change any of the underlying definitions seems to indicate it's some other kind of issue. But I don't know where it could be stemming from.

I would appreciate any help to figure this out!

---

UPDATE:

First, Akhilesh, thank you for the reply. Your suggestions did not directly lead to a solution but they at least got me into the spirit of trial and error.

I have found two "solutions" to this problem.

The first is to set "line-height: 0px;" inside of the container in "Additional CSS." This isn't ideal because it means that I can't type regular text in this container anymore. Not very elegant.

The second kind of seems like a fluke. As I showed above, my posts begin with:

```
<div class="container">**here**<img class="aligncenter wp-image-8056 size-full" style="width: 100%;" src="https://*mysite*/wp-content/uploads/thx-1138-film-confession.png" alt="Robert Duvall as THX 1138" width="831" height="364">
```

That is a single, unbroken line of code. By starting a new line where I indicate above, it solves the issue. As I stated in my initial description, I have not changed anything. All my posts have been like this since I decided on the format. And as Akhilesh stated, it works in the fiddler (which was a new tool for me, so thanks again).

So, problem solved, but what changed to cause the issue? Something in the way that Wordpress interprets HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the `img` element : `display:block;`

Also, try to find whether there's any padding/margin set for the `h2` and `h6` elements.

Because I don't see any issues when I tried. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vL80u1a2/

If that didn't helped, try using the Developer Tools in your browser. Just right click on the element and choose `Inspect Element`. Then when you select an element on the left side, all CSS would appear on the right pane. You can try trouble shooting for the padding using that Developer Tools.

Have a look at this for more details on how to use the Developer Tools: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css

Comment: Akhilesh, thanks for your input. I figured out two different possible solutions and added them to my original post.

Comment: @netlocf Which code editor are you using? My guess is that, some unicode character might be getting inserted on that line (before `<img>`) which is being rendered as blank.